# Correlation between products

Tags: correlation

I have an idea of what I want to achieve, but have no clue what it is called in statistical analysis world, hence impossible to implement.

I have a database with unique order numbers, customer names, products etc. I would like to see the correlation between products within orders. I.e. if I pick product X, what is the likelihood that I will also choose a product Y.

I would like to know what to research to help me with this.

Comment: Thank you all for your input! I will try these and come back to you.

Comment: I have found that Data Mining add-in for excel can do wonders, but while add-in itself is free, it uses SQL Server's Analysis Services module, which unfortunately is not included in free products. Maybe somebody knows some other way that could be implemented in Excel?

Comment: I notice that you’ve edited your title to say “[solved]”. If one of the answers has addressed your problem, the way that you show that is by accepting an answer: click the check mark next to the answer that helped you the most. Please review the [help] for more information about how to use this website.

Answer (score 1):

Such relationships are called *association rules*.

One of the widely used algorithms for deriving association rules is *Apriori*, which is implemented in both [R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/) and [Python](http://orange.biolab.si/docs/latest/reference/rst/Orange.associate.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's called conditional probability $P(Y|X)$, i.e. probability of picking Y given that a customer picked X. There are relationships such as this one: $P(Y\&X)=P(Y|X)P(X)$, i.e. the probability that you pick Y and X is equal to probability of picking X multiplied by probability of picking Y conditional on picking X etc.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you're wondering if the event where an individual chooses product $X$ is independent of the event where they choose product $Y$, or if these events are positively correlated.  You can check this by testing the hypothesis $p_1 = p_0$ against the alternative $p_1 > p_0$, where $p_1$ is the probability of choosing product $Y$ given that you've chosen product $X$, and $p_0$ is the same probability given that you didn't choose product $X$.  If your sample sizes are large you can test this with the statistic
$$
z = \frac{\hat{p}_1 - \hat{p}_0}{ \sqrt{\frac{\hat{p} (1 - \hat{p})}{n_1} + \frac{\hat{p} (1 - \hat{p})}{n_0}} }
$$
where $\hat{p}_1$ is the proportion of individuals who purchased product $Y$ among those who purchased product $X$, $\hat{p}_0$ is the proportion among those who didn't purchase product $X$ ($n_1$ and $n_0$ are the respective sample sizes), and $\hat{p}$ is the overall proportion.  When $p_1 = p_0$ this approximately follows a standard normal distribution, which can be used for the calculation of $p$-values.  Do you know where to go from here?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit on further steps?

Comment: This seems to explain the test: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/268